# problemas con condición

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como puedo arrojar un mensaje que si no se encuentra en SELECT que diga "Numero Disponible" este es mi código:

```
      if(isset ($_GET['enviar'])) {
        $busqueda = $_GET['buscar'];
        $busqueda = $_GET['buscar'];
        $consulta = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE nroPiloto = '$busqueda'");
        echo '<div  style="font-size:1.25em;color:yellow;text-align:center;font-weight:bold">Nro Ya en uso! </div>';
    }
```

Comment: Pues cuenta cuántos datos trae la ejecución de esa consulta y si es cero, pintas lo que dices que quieres pintar

Comment: @Alfabravo trae un dato numérico que se busca a través de formulario ese formulario arrojara un mensaje dependiendo del resultado y lo encuentra o no en la base de datos

Comment: Entonces lee el dato numérico y usa un condicional

Comment: Tal vez SELECT Count(*) FROM RESERVAS Where ...  (Mejor que use parámetros)